# When creating a matrix, I get the error that "Index exceeds matrix dimensions"

Tags: matlab, matrix

I wanted to create with each vector a Matrix V, but I get this error Index exceeds matrix dimensions. I don't see why this should not work, am I missing something?

```
x1=[1 2 3];
x2=[1 4 3];
x3=[1 5 3];
x4=[1 6 3];
x=[];
V=[];    


for i=1:1:4
         V=[ones(size(x(i))) x(i)]
end

v =

     []


V =

     []

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish?

In your for-loop your index i goes from 1 to 4 inclusive. Yet, you try to access x(i) where x is an empty array. Therefore, in your first iteration (i=1) you are accessing x(1) which is not defined. This results in an Index out of bounds error.

Also for using the ones() function you should separate the input arguments by a comma:
`ones(size(x(i)), x(i))`

**Code example**

```
x = [1 2 3; 1 4 3; 1 5 3; 1 6 3];
V = zeros(size(x, 1), 1);  % initialize V
for i = 1:1:size(x, 1)
    V(i) = x(i, 1);
end
```

This example returns a vector of first elements from each row of your matrix x.

```
V = [1; 1; 1; 1]
```

Comment: I am trying to create matrix with each vector looking like this
V= 1 1 1 1 2 3 and so

so in the loop is should get access to x1, x2, x3, x4
 so i is supposed to be the index and thats why i wrote it in this way x(i)

Comment: Ahh, I see. The problem is that x(i) accesses elements of a variable x. If you want to iterate over different vectors I recommend that you construct a matrix `x = [x1; x2; x3; x4]` and iterate over its rows `x(i, :)` with `for i=1:1:4`.

Comment: You're welcome! I've added an example to the code. If my answer helped you please make sure to accept it :)

Comment: I have accepted it , but I was wondering how to save all outputs of this loop because even you have written V(i) .. it just saves one vector

Comment: Depends on what your output should be. In your code you overwrite V in each iteration. If you want to save it persistently you can iteratively fill out a matrix that you initialize in advance, as I did in my example.